# How to recreate issue: Mysql2::Error: Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can anyone suggest how to recreate issue `Mysql2::Error: Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT)`

This was triggered due API `/admin/products` and "action"=>"index".

Error:

```
/admin/products#GET params: { "controller"=>"admin/products"}, 
exception: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid, message: Mysql2::Error:
 Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and 
(utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'
```

Comment: Can you please add the controller method's code and how the like query looks like? Please check what collation you configured in your database.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong character set. Try using UTF-8, add the following at the top of your offending file:

```
#!/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8
```